# How to check if a given value is a date or not

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I import a data form CSV file and store it in an Oracle table. 
Is there a predefined PL/SQL function for checking if a given value is a date or not?

If not, how can I validate to confirm that the value is a date?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Literal does not match format string" when comparing two date fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339047/literal-does-not-match-format-string-when-comparing-two-date-fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_date() function to check wether your value is a date. Though Oracle wouldn't let you store non-date type into date type column.

Here's a simple example how to check if some value is a date:

```
Declare  
  v_data Clob := 'sdf';
  v_date Date;
begin
  v_date := to_date(v_data);
  exception When others Then 
    dbms_output.put_line(v_data||' Is not a date');
end;
```

Comment: The problem is that if you don't provide the date model format, it will be taken from NLS_DATE_FORMAT, so you will only know if the input string is in that format, or not.

Comment: I agree, though @Duleep didnt give any kind of data, and I assumed his csv file date fields would all be same format, in which case you could easily add format parameter to to_date funcion.

Comment: True :) would be kinda hard to tell if something is a date when you don't know the model format. Hope the author doesn't have to do it! Cheers.